# Django - Model field define unicode

Tags: python, django, django-models

As we can define the `__unicode__` representation of a model,
Is there a way to define the same for a model field ? (or is it a bad idea ?)

Comment: there is `verbose_name` for field...

Comment: I'm talking about the value representation, not the field name.

Comment: Can you show a particular usecase that you're curious about?

Comment: @Ngenator gave us [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21783804/305189)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own methods. For example, when you use `choices` for a field, django automatically creates a `get_FIELD_display` method for the `FIELD`.

```
class Something(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def get_name_uppercase(self):
        return self.name.upper()
```

then when you have

```
something = Something.get(id=1)
```

you can access it via

```
something.get_name_uppercase()
```